# Unable to show php variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am unable to show php variable in javascript;

this is my code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    var n=<?php echo json_encode($count)?>;
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "d5";
        div.id=i+1;
        document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(div);
        <?php
        $query="select * from shop_product where shop_uniqueid='$unq'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $product=$row["in_product"];
        ?>
        var product=<?php echo $product?>;

        $('#'+div.id).html(product);

        <?php
        }
        ?>



    }//for loop ends


    });//ready ends
</script>
```

here i am trying to pass `var product` in html() of which value is coming from php like: `var product=<?php echo $product?>;`

but when doing so php value is not coming in Javascript's `var product`.
when I pass `$('#'+div.id).html("abcd");` abcd value is showing in divs.

please help me.

Comment: Try to change `var product=<?php echo $product?>;` to `var product='<?php echo $product?>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the first place you take data from PHP and put it in JavaScript:

```
    var n=<?php echo json_encode($count)?>;
```

with your attempt to assign the product value:

```
    var product=<?php echo $product?>;
```

You haven't converted the data from *plain text* to *JavaScript* in the second line. Use `json_encode` there too.